# AngularJS '$apply already in progress' when click a button with tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button in a view that, when I click it I get the '$apply already in progress error' even before the ng-click is executed.

Here's my button:

```
<button class="btn"
        ng-show="vm.enableButton()"
        ng-click="vm.doStuff()"
        tooltip="Loads values."
        ng-disabled="vm.data.IsReadonly">
    <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>Load
</button>
```

When the code hits the alert at the start of 'doStuff()', the error has already appeared in the console.

Here's my controller (ala John Papa style)

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller(controllerId, ['$q', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$window', 'common', 'config', 'datacontext', detail]);

function detail($q, $routeParams, $scope, $window, common, config, datacontext) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.data = {};
    vm.doStuff = doStuff;
    vm.enableButton = enableButton;

    function doStuff() {
       alert('in do stuff');
    }

    function enableButton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I took out the tooltip attribute, the ng-click started working with no error.  Is there a workaround for this?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Corey.

Comment: I think you may want to show us your implementation of those methods

Comment: Usually this happens when you are calling into angular code from non-angular code (a non-angular event handler or ajax request, for example.)

Comment: Likely.  Where is the non-angular code here?

Comment: Can you turn your code into a fiddle to reproduce the issue? Based on the above I don't see the problem. I agree with Geoff, it's got to be something else.

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the tooltip. I updated the question.

Comment: You probably have some javascript associated with the tooltip -- what library are you using for it?